# .m4a file is not playing while uploading to server

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, m4a

In my app i am uploading **.m4a** music file from iphone library (storing in core data) which is downloaded from itunes, problem is the uploaded file is not playing (even in browser), some times the uploaded file is of 4MB size, in server it is showing 20KB. If i upload a **.mp3** file it is perfectly uploading and perfectly playing. please help me.My code follows like this.

```
[request addData:[managedobject valueForKey:@"songData"] withFileName:[managedobject valueForKey:@"song_name"] andContentType:nil forKey:@"file"];


[request setPostValue:[managedobject valueForKey:@"song_extension"] forKey:@"extension"];
```

Comment: If the file is 20KB on the server, then the upload probably failed. Check your upload code...

Comment: even fully uploaded file is also not playing ...nneonneo

Comment: i got same problem.... but not fixed somebody said its server end problem.....

Comment: Try printing the length of the data before upload. If it's 20K in length, check the database code, if it's greater, check your networking code or the server's implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try manually uploading the file to your server to verify that it will play at all... because of Apples Fairplay (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FairPlay) DRM, I have had trouble playing songs bought off the store as well. However, if this is not the case, then recheck your upload code because something is wrong.